# Css positioning in joomla 1.5 template

Tags: css, joomla-template

I've been trying to make a joomla template with on the left and on the right a bar with fixed width. the main div should be responsive.

I managed to create the layout what i want here:
http://dennybeulen.nl/rena/nl/over-ons.html

The only thing what is not working is the menu on the left side. When i change the css the menu works, but the layout is not right anymore.

the menu is working if i make these changes (just removed the '-' in front of 130):

```
div.fluid{
     margin-left: 130px;
}
```

hope somebody can give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `div.fluid` is covering your left column.
Try making `div.left` absolutely positioned and setting your `div.fluid` to having no left margin:

```
div.fluid{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -290px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
div.left{
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Keep in mind, div.left will no longer affect elements floating against it.

Answer (score 0):

@gaynorvader is right in that your middle container lays on top of the menu. Instead of positioning it absolute, you could also just leave everything as is, and only add `position:relative;z-index:1` for `div.left`.